# Decompose coerced time series object R

Tags: r

I am trying to decompose a time series object. I have coerced a xts object into time series

To know the structure of my time series object

```
sapply(ts_group1_ts, class)
      store        item   yearmonth total_sales 
       "ts"        "ts"        "ts"        "ts"
>decompose(ts_group1_ts[,'total_sales'])

Error in `-.default`(x, trend) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I want to decompose the total sales part of my time series . Please tell how to decompose. I realise that the **error is because the function is not identifying total_sales as integer**. How to achieve that in time series object

On doing forced conversion to numeric I get below output:

```
    >decompose(as.numeric(ts_group1_ts[,'total_sales']))
    Error in decompose(as.numeric(ts_group1_ts[, "total_sales"])) : 
    time series has no or less than 2 periods
```

But the frequency of my time series is 12

```
     >frequency(ts_group1_ts)
      12
```

Comment: could you dput(head(ts_group1_ts, n = 24)) to help with testing some ideas? Is seasonality or trend important? Is the data monthly (12 seems to suggest it). And did you coerce using seq.POSIXt()? Thanks.